# Angular app working locally but returns 404 when deployed

Tags: angular, deployment, rxjs, localhost, http-status-code-404

I have the following code for component, that is displaying modal on top of main page (just like instagram)
The main page is displaying whole gallery at url.com, while specified url for single post
(url.com/photo/1) returns 404 while deployed on github pages, but works great at local server.

Here is my code for the component that is assigned to /post/:postId url:

PostEntryComponent.ts

```
  constructor(public dialog: MatDialog,
              public router: Router,
              public route: ActivatedRoute,
              private postService: PostService) {

    this.route.paramMap.pipe(
      take(1),
      switchMap(paramMap => {
        const id = paramMap.get('postId');
        return this.postService.getPostData(+id);
      })
    ).subscribe(data => {
      const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(PostModalComponent,
        {
          autoFocus: false,
          backdropClass: 'backdrop-background',
          data: {
            image: data.image,
            text: data.text
          }
        });
      dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(() => {
        this.router.navigate(['../../'], {relativeTo: this.route});
      });
    });
  }
}
```

PostService.ts

```
  getPostData(postId: number): Observable<Post> {
    return this.profileInfo.asObservable().pipe(
      switchMap((data: ProfileData) => {
        if (!data || data.posts.length <= 0) {
          return this.fetchProfileData();
        } else {
          return of(data);
        }
      }),
      skipWhile(data => data.posts.length < 1),
      take(1),
      map((data: ProfileData) => {
          if (data.posts) {
            return data.posts.find(p => p.id === postId);
          }
        }
      ));
  }
```

Routing module:

```
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      {
        path: '',
        component: ShellComponent,
        children: [
          {
            path: 'post/:postId',
            component: PostEntryComponent
          }
        ]
      },
      { path: '**', redirectTo: 'home' }
    ])
```

my app.component.html contains only:

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

and my shell.component.ts also contains `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` at the end so when somebody click at photo modal popups. Based on [this solution](https://stackblitz.com/edit/material-dialog-route-dialog-path-oguqel?file=app%2Fdialog-overview-example.ts)

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you show your routing module?

Comment: @Benny I edded it to main post.